# Proper way to reset csv.reader for multiple iterations?

Tags: python, csv, iterator

Having an issue with a custom iterator in that it will only iterate over the file once. I am calling `seek(0)` on the relevant file object in between iterations, but `StopIteration` is thrown on the first call to `next()` on the 2nd run through. I feel I am overlooking something obvious, but would appreciate some fresh eyes on this:

```
class MappedIterator(object):
    """
    Given an iterator of dicts or objects and a attribute mapping dict, 
    will make the objects accessible via the desired interface.

    Currently it will only produce dictionaries with string values. Can be 
    made to support actual objects later on. Somehow... :D
    """

    def __init__(self, obj=None, mapping={}, *args, **kwargs):

        self._obj = obj
        self._mapping = mapping
        self.cnt = 0

    def __iter__(self):

        return self

    def reset(self):

        self.cnt = 0

    def next(self):

        try:

            try:
                item = self._obj.next()
            except AttributeError:
                item = self._obj[self.cnt]

            # If no mapping is provided, an empty object will be returned.
            mapped_obj = {}

            for mapped_attr in self._mapping:

                attr = mapped_attr.attribute
                new_attr = mapped_attr.mapped_name

                val = item.get(attr, '')
                val = str(val).strip() # get rid of whitespace

                # TODO: apply transformers...

                # This allows multi attribute mapping or grouping of multiple
                # attributes in to one.
                try:
                    mapped_obj[new_attr] += val
                except KeyError:
                    mapped_obj[new_attr] = val

            self.cnt += 1

            return mapped_obj

        except (IndexError, StopIteration):

            self.reset()
            raise StopIteration


class CSVMapper(MappedIterator):

    def __init__(self, reader, mapping={}, *args, **kwargs):

        self._reader = reader
        self._mapping = mapping

        self._file = kwargs.pop('file')

        super(CSVMapper, self).__init__(self._reader, self._mapping, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, file, mapping, *args, **kwargs):

        # TODO: Parse kwargs for various DictReader kwargs.
        return cls(reader=DictReader(file), mapping=mapping, file=file)

    def __len__(self):

      return int(self._reader.line_num)

    def reset(self):

      if self._file:

        self._file.seek(0)

      super(CSVMapper, self).reset()
```

Sample usage:

```
file = open('somefile.csv', 'rb') # say this file has 2 rows + a header row

mapping = MyMappingClass() # this isn't really relevant

reader = CSVMapper.from_csv(file, mapping)

# > 'John'
# > 'Bob'
for r in reader:

  print r['name']

# This won't print anything
for r in reader:

  print r['name']
```

Comment: The docs say that not all file objects can use seek(), although it doesn't say which types. I'd guess not text files but might be worth investigating http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html

Comment: Also, if you wanted to can you not just re-open or re-instantiate the `reader` object again to get the desired effect?

Comment: Oh that brings up a good point. This is an instance of Django's file object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/file/

Comment: Related: [Can iterators be reset in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3266180/95735)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that you are better off not trying to do the `.seek(0)` but rather opening the file from the filename each time.

And I don't recommend you just return `self` in the `__iter__()` method.  That means you only ever have one instance of your object.  I don't know how likely it is for someone to try to use your object from two different threads, but if that happened the results would be surprising.

So, save the filename, and then in the `__iter__()` method, create a fresh object with a freshly initialized reader object and a freshly opened file handle object; return this new object from `__iter__()`.  This will work every time, no matter what the file-like object really is.  It could be a handle to a networking function that is pulling data from a server, or who knows what, and it might not support a `.seek()` method; but you know that if you just open it again you will get a fresh file handle object.  And if someone uses the `threading` module to run 10 instances of your class in parallel, each one will always get all of the lines from the file, instead of each randomly getting about a tenth of the lines.

Also, I don't recommend your exception handler inside the `.next()` method in `MappedIterator`.  The `.__iter__()` method should return an object that can be reliably iterated.  If a silly user passes in an integer object (for example: 3), this won't be iterable.  Inside `.__iter__()` you can always explicitly call `iter()` on an argument, and if it is already an iterator (for example, an open file handle object) you will just get the same object back; but if it is a sequence object, you will get an iterator that works on the sequence.  Now if the user passes in 3, the call to `iter()` will raise an exception that makes sense right at the line where the user passed the 3, rather than the exception coming from the first call to `.next()`.  And as a bonus, you don't need the `cnt` member variable anymore, and your code will be a little bit faster.

So, if you put together all my suggestions, you might get something like this:

```
class CSVMapper(object):
    def __init__(self, reader, fname, mapping={}, **kwargs):
        self._reader = reader
        self._fname = fname
        self._mapping = mapping
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        self.line_num = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        cls = type(self)
        obj = cls(self._reader, self._fname, self._mapping, **self._kwargs)
        if "open_with" in self._kwargs:
            open_with = self._kwargs["open_with"]
            f = open_with(self._fname, **self._kwargs)
        else:
            f = open(self._fname, "rt")
        # "itr" is my standard abbreviation for an iterator instance
        obj.itr = obj._reader(f)
        return obj

    def next(self):
        item = self.itr.next()
        self.line_num += 1

        # If no mapping is provided, item is returned unchanged.
        if not self._mapping:
            return item  # csv.reader() returns a list of string values

        # we have a mapping so make a mapped object
        mapped_obj = {}

        key, value = item
        if key in self._mapping:
            return [self._mapping[key], value]
        else:
            return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst_csv = [
        "foo, 0",
        "one, 1",
        "two, 2",
        "three, 3",
    ]

    import csv
    mapping = {"foo": "bar"}
    m = CSVMapper(csv.reader, lst_csv, mapping, open_with=iter)

    for item in m: # will print every item
        print item

    for item in m: # will print every item again
        print item
```

Now the `.__iter__()` method gives you a fresh object every time you call it.

Note how the example code uses a list of strings instead of opening a file.  In this example, you need to specify an `open_with()` function to be used instead of the default `open()` to open the file.  Since our list of strings can be iterated to return one string at a time, we can simply use `iter` as our `open_with` function here.

I didn't understand your mapping code.  `csv.reader` returns a list of string values, not some kind of a dictionary, so I wrote some trivial mapping code that works for CSV files with two columns, the first one a string.  Clearly you should chop out my trivial mapping code and put in the desired mapping code.

Also, I took out your `.__len__()` method.  This returns the length of a sequence when you do something like `len(obj)`; you had it returning `line_num` which means that the value of `len(obj)` would change every time you call the `.next()` method.  If users want to know the length, they should store the results in a list and take the length of the list, or something like that.

EDIT: I added `**self._kwargs` to the call to `call_with()` in the `.__iter__()` method.  That way, if your `call_with()` function needs any extra arguments they will be passed through.  Before I made this change, there wasn't really a good reason to save the `kwargs` argument in the object; it would have been just as good to add a `call_with` argument to the class `.__init__()` method, with a default argument of `None`.  I think this change is a good one.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for all the additional tips. The `.__len__` was more of a sanity check for myself while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

For DictReader:

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
d = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")

f.seek(0)
d.__init__(f, delimiter=",")
```

For DictWriter:

```
f = open(filename, "rb+")
d = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=",")

f.seek(0)
f.truncate(0)
d.__init__(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=",")
d.writeheader()
f.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DictReader` object does not appear to follow a `seek()` command on the open file, so the `next()` calls are continually made from the end of the file.

In your `reset` you could reopen the file (you will also need to store the filename in `self._filename`):

```
def reset(self):
     if self._file:
         self._file.close()
         self._file = open(self._filename, 'rb')
```

You could also look at subclassing your file object similarly to the top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001201/using-python-csv-module-on-updating-file) question.